# Why not working , <go to next=""> after step when run vxml

Tags: xml, ivr, vxml

I develop the Jax-rs web service, I want to out put as VXML then I got VXML like this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<vxml version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.xsd">
     <form>
         <block>
            <audio src="{url1}" />
            <goto next="{url2}" />
         </block>
        <noinput>
            <reprompt />
        </noinput>
        <nomatch>
            <reprompt />
        </nomatch>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

There  `<audio src="{url1}" />`  not working but second step working `<goto next="{url2}" />` this working. This application test  using IVR (Interactive voice response ) . Is this my fault or IVR fault ? How to this solve?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an obvious mistake. Insure that the file is retrievable and add fallback text, if a TTS engine is available.  If the text is played, it would imply a problem fetching the audio.

Comment: <goto next="{url1}"/> When remove this VXML working then play prompt using audio but I use <goto next="{url2}" /> when didn't play any voice prompt. why this happen?

Comment: Is there anything in the destination form that could be preventing the audio from playing; like a hang up?  Audio is usually queued.  Unless you perform an input, the hangup or other actions will be performed while the audio plays.

Comment: how that time set I am looking for answer..